# Convertion array ['xx=yy'] to map of xx=yy

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, angular5

i have an array of object like this ["statusCode=1"] but i need it as "statusCode"="1"

Comment: So what have you done so far? What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [tag:angular5] and [tag:java]?

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can use stream to convert your array to map. I think below code snippet might help you:

```
Map<String,String> resultMap =  Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(elem-> elem.split("="))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(val-> val[0], val-> val[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript / Typescript you can map the array and split the string on '='

```
var array = ["statusCode=1"];
var object = array.map(v => {
  let keyValueArr = v.split('=');
  return { [keyValueArr[0]]: keyValueArr[1] }
});
console.log(object)
```

Comment: I used it by splitting it with '=' and set in the map